# Use of data parameter in ajax call with forms

Tags: jquery

I have multiple forms in a view and I am submiting them via jquery, I am doing an ajax like this example in each form:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/Providers/Add",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Name: $("#Name").val(),
                Phone: $("#Phone").val(),
                Email: $("#Email").val(),
                Country: $("#Country").val(),
                State: $("#State").val(),
                Address: $("#Address").val()
            }),
            succes: function(result) {
                $('#mdlnewprovider').hide();
            }
        });
```

My problem now is that I have the id Name in many forms, I know one solution would be to change my names like #Name1, #Name2 ... #nameN, but I dont like this option since it will be a mess.

I was trying to do something like this, but it is not working:

```
data: JSON.stringify($('#frmeditprovider').serializeArray())
```

so now I only have to worry about having unique forms, not unique fields, wich will be easier, so what is the correct way to do this?

in advance thanks.

Comment: The correct way would be to have actual unique idenfiers, as using the same ID more than once is invalid no matter what you think.

Comment: my forms are strongly typed forms with asp mvc, thats the problem that for example I have a class person with a propety name, then I have a class studdent with a property name too, asp mvc by default gives them the Id of the property name

Comment: Anything you try will fail, as `$('#frmeditprovider')` will only get the first element with that ID, it won't even look for any other elements with that ID, as there should be only one. The only workaround is a bad one, using `$('[id="frmeditprovider"]')` will get all the elements as it's based on the attribute instead, but again, it's less efficient, and it's just a hack as the real problem is multiple ID's

Comment: thanks, I will make unique Id's like frm-edit-field-name. I am displaying popups, thats why they repeat. my forms can appear everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You should try directly `serializeArray` without `JSON.stringify`:

```
data: $('#frmeditprovider').serializeArray();
```

Hopefully, this should work. To learn more about it: Reference: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: thanks but I am getting this error too: [ArgumentException]: Invalid JSON primitive: Id. maybe something is wrong with my html, my identifiers repeat maybe is that

Comment: This will help: (http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) and (http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/). Also, (http://forum.jquery.com/topic/invalid-json-primitive-error-while-using-ajax)

Comment: I believe, this will help:  [jquery-json](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) and then `data: $.toJSON($('#frmeditprovider').serializeArray()[0]),`.